# How to change default focus behaviour in firemonkey control

Tags: delphi, custom-component, firemonkey, delphi-xe4, firemonkey-fm3

I have created a custom Styledcontrol descendant, that consist out of 3 TEdit's that represent a date (Day/month/hour), the Edits are part of my .style file

When the control gets focus, the first Edit should get focus. the other edits should never get focus through tabbing. they have tabstop = false in the style file.

```
constructor TPWCalendar.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
Oncanfocus:=FocusEdit;

procedure TPWCalendar.FocusEdit(Sender: TObject; var ACanFocus: Boolean);
begin
  ACanFocus:=false;
  if Findedits then
    if not FDayEdit.isfocused then
      FDayEdit.SetFocus;
end;
```

This works, but when one of the children Edits is focused, and i press tab, the first edit of the first created custom control is selected. **How to make it have default behaviour and select the next control as if it was 1 control?** (So no matter where the focus lies in the control - edit1, edit2 or edit3, pressing tab should select the next control).

PS: Is there any decent firemonkey component tutorial? considering styling etc.

*I have updated the question*

Comment: Edit Events does not apply to navigation keys Tab as these do not trigger keyboard events. The only place which points to this fact.[Delphi Help TCustomForm.KeyPreview](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/de/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.KeyPreview) . And my answer [tab event in TEdit](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16888843/1322642) .

Comment: @moskito-x, this is Firemonkey not VCL.

Comment: @PeterVonča : The behavior is the same. Look for `KeyUp` event here [How to trap TAB keypresses on FireMonkey form](https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=447052)

Comment: @moskito-x, there is no keyPreview form property in Firemonkey. That's why I said what I said. But yeah you're correct about trapping Tab in Keyup event.

Comment: If you override procedure DialogKey in your component, you can control the behavior on Tab key. DialogKey is called from the form on KeyDown.

Comment: Question has been updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the main problem.

By setting a private oncanfocusEvent, the first child (FDayEdit) is selected.
Then i overwrite DialogKey, when one of my childs is focused, the main component gets focus (note that this triggers the oncanfocusevent). then default behaviour is called with inherrited.

thnx slomoto for showing me in the right direction.

PS: FindEdits assigns the Edits from the styleresource,and returns false if failed.

This is the oncanfocusEvent:

```
procedure TPWCalendar.FocusEdit(Sender: TObject; var ACanFocus: Boolean);
begin
  if findedits and ( fDayEdit.IsFocused or FMonthEdit.IsFocused or FYearEdit.IsFocused)
    then aCanFocus:=true
    else begin
      ACanFocus:=false;
      if Findedits then
        FDayEdit.SetFocus;
    end;
end;
```

Then This is the DialogKey Event

```
procedure TPWCalendar.DialogKey(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if key=vktab then
    if ischildfocused then begin
      self.SetFocus;
      inherited;
    end;
end;
```